# Login page in Asp.Net -IMPROVEMENT

Tags: asp.net, authentication, cryptography, scrypt

I recently did a registration and  login page in ASP.NET and I hashed the password using SCRYPT and saved it to the database. I feel like my project is not complete, I would like to add something unique to it(something related to cryptography). What do you recommend me?

Comment: We don't normally make our own hashed algorithm in ASP.Net, since ASP.Net already have Identity, Universal Providers and Membership Provider. What are you looking for?

Comment: I'm looking for something different, because is a project for school and I have to focus a little bit more on the security part :-D

Answer (score 0):

> a project for school and I have to focus a little bit more on the
>   security part

If you want industry standard User Login with highest security, you can look at ASP.Net Identity.

It is a steep learning curve at first, so you can start with [ASP.NET identity by Adam Freeman](http://www.apress.com/9781430265290) which is free at [Apress](http://www.apress.com/9781430265290).

It is worth learning it if you want to develop Web Applications in the future, since you can reuse the same code again and again.